# SQL - how to perform an intersection on the same table (with a subquery) using joins?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables. Car table, and rental table.

Car:

```
id brand
--------
0  honda
1  yota
```

Rental:

```
id id_car start end
--------
1  1      1     2
2  1      2     NULL
```

I need to execute two queries. One that shows all cars that are rented. The other that shows all cars that are NOT rented.

The first query was easy for me.

```
SELECT car.id, car.brand, reg.start, reg.end
FROM car
LEFT JOIN car_registration AS reg ON car.id = reg.id_car
WHERE reg.end IS NULL
```

The reverse query (for determining rented cars) would involve something along the lines of the opposite. Find a list of rentals, where reg.id_car = car.idm where reg.end IS NOT NULL. However, if an entry exists in the same table where reg.end IS NULL, then the car is actually rented. I need to intersect a list of car rentals where reg.end IS NULL and renteals where reg.end IS NOT NULL.

Pseudo-sql would be something like this.

Select DISTINCT car.id (so that duplicate historical rentals are not returned), join with car rentals table, where reg.end is NOT NULL. This would give me all cars that are not rented (expired rentals). However, I need to intersect this with a list of car rentals where reg.end IS null, in order to determine that the car is in-fact not rented.

I know SQL doesn't have an intersect statement. I get how joins work in principle, but this is confusing the hell out of me. Any ideas?

Comment: "Registered"?  "rented"?  It is very hard to follow your question.

Comment: Just edited. Sorry! Original application involves something I can't post about, I totally modified the example to be more consistent.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.
Obviously, feel free to construct a dummy data set if your real environment is sensitive in some way. Just be consistent with your input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can get both rented and unrented cars in a single query by simply left joining the car table against a subselect where you determine cars that are currently rented out.

```
SELECT
    c.id AS id,
    c.brand AS brand,
    r.rented AS rented
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            brand
        FROM car
    ) AS c
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            id_car,
            1 AS rented
        FROM car_registration
        WHERE `end` IS NULL
    ) AS r
ON c.id = r.id_car
```

All rows where you have `1` for `rented` would signify cars that are currently being rented out.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to test now. Do you have any idea why my question is down voted? I thought it was valid, but definitely willing to improve it some way.

Comment: I got this error:  `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: @NewToMS I don't know why it would be downvoted, as it looked fine to me, at least when I initially saw it. I do see comments about confusion in first version, so maybe that was it.

Comment: @NewToMS Those tables have aliases (the `AS c` and `AS r` parts). Did you omit that part?

Comment: They're definitely there! Everything else was ported with precision to match my example. Humm, there used to be a 'chat' option when I first signed up here. Is it gone?

Comment: @NewToMS I don't know what could be causing that as those are the only two derived tables being used here.  Could you set up an SQL fiddle to see if this can be replicated?

Comment: @NewToMS I see the issue.  I accidentally typed an extra `)` in there after `FROM car`.  I have now edited my answer to correct.

Comment: @NewToMS By the way. Here is a fiddle showing this works now.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a57dc5/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64968/discussion-between-newtoms-and-mike-brant).